# Insert Trigger Causing EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, postgresql, triggers, entity, persistence

I could use some assistance figuring this one out. I've wasted a day hunting for an answer without finding anything.

I have an Entity and Model class. The Entity is the simplistic data and the Model is the controller for the Entity. On the database, I have a trigger that when an AFTER INSERT happens, the trigger is sprung to update another table's information. What's happening is that after the EntityManager's persist and flush, refresh is called and it's causing an "EntityNotFoundException". If I take out the insert on the trigger, then everything is honky dory. Here's the code below:

**Method that gets the ball rolling**

```
    public FTL createPaymentByAccountNumberLoanNumber(String accountNumber, Integer loanNumber, Payment payment) {

        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

        Loan loan = checkLastLoan(accountNumber, loanNumber);

        BigDecimal totalAmount =
                payment.getAppliedToBalance()
                .add(payment.getAppliedToXXX())
                .add(payment.getAppliedToYYY())
                .add(payment.getAppliedToZZZ());

        FT ft = new FT ();            
        ft.setTransactionAmount(totalAmount);
        em.persist(ft);

        FTL lastFtl = FTL.loadLastByLoan(loan);
        em.detach(lastFtl);

        FTL ftl = new FTL(ft);
        ftl.setTransactionAmount(totalAmount);
        ftl.setAppliedToBalance(payment.getAppliedToBalance());
        ftl.setAppliedToXXX(payment.getAppliedToLateCharge());
        ftl.setAppliedToYYY(payment.getAppliedToMaturityInterest());
        ftl.setAppliedToZZZ(payment.getAppliedToNsfCharge());
        ftl.setTransactionCode(TransactionCode.Collection);
        ftl.setNewEndingBalance(lastFtl.getNewEndingBalance().subtract(payment.getAppliedToBalance()));
        ftl.setLoan(loan);

        em.persist(ftl);
        em.flush();         
        em.refresh(ft);
        em.refresh(ftl); //THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURES WHEN GOING THROUGH DEBUG
        em.detach(ftl);

        evict(Loan.class, loan.getLoanId());

        return ftl;
    }
```

**FTL_loan_movement_trigger**

```
    CREATE TRIGGER FTL_loan_movement_trigger
    AFTER INSERT
    ON FTL
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE loan_movement_trigger();
```

**loan_movement_trigger**

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loan_movement_trigger()
      RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
        _loan_id bigint;
        _loan_movement_status integer;
        _loan_current_status integer;
        _ending_balance numeric;
    BEGIN
      _loan_id := NEW.loan_id;

      RAISE NOTICE 'Finding the statuses of the loan: %', _loan_id;

      --Find the currently saved off status of the loan
      _loan_movement_status := (SELECT fls.status FROM find_loan_status(_loan_id, now()::date) fls);
      --Calculate the current status of the loan
      _loan_current_status  := (SELECT * FROM calc_loan_current_status(_loan_id) clcs);

      RAISE NOTICE 'Movement % and Current %', _loan_movement_status, _loan_current_status;

      IF(_loan_movement_status != _loan_current_status) THEN
         _ending_balance := (SELECT * FROM calc_ending_balance(_loan_id, now()::date));

         RAISE NOTICE 'New ending balance: %', _ending_balance;
    --/*  THIS INSERT RIGHT HERE IS WHAT IS CAUSING THE EXCEPTION!!!!!!!
         INSERT INTO loan_movement
        (movement_date,
            loan_id,
            status,
            remaining_balance,  
            created_by,
            organization_id) 
        VALUES
        (now(), 
            9999999, 
            _loan_current_status, 
            _ending_balance,
            1,
            1);

         RAISE NOTICE 'Inserted into loan_movement';
     --*/

      END IF;
      RETURN NEW;

    END;
```

Comment: As *always*, your version of Postgres please. Also, if the trigger function raises an exception like your comment in the code says, there should be an error message in the Postgres log. You need to post the *verbatim* error message. Also, your function definition is incomplete (no `LANGUAGE` declaration). Please post the *complete* definition.

Comment: Definitions of the auxiliary functions `find_loan_status()`, `calc_loan_current_status()` and `calc_ending_balance()` would be of interest, too. All of those may be expendable.

Comment: I am sitting on top of PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: I am unable to provide the find_loan_status(), calc_loan_current_status(), or the calc_ending_balance() since these are proprietary code.

Comment: Well, at least the function signature (fields expected and returned). Those functions are probably trivial and might be replaced and integrated into the query.

Answer (score 1):

PL/pgSQL is supposed to be the glue for server-side execution of (multiple) SQL statements. Don't modularize your code with sub-functions and assignments like you would in a procedural language like Java, that's very inefficient. Try to use few SQL statements that do much work at once. Build your plpgsql code around that.

Your trigger functions can be largely simplified with a ***single*** SQL statement:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loan_movement_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   WITH loan AS (SELECT calc_loan_current_status(NEW.loan_id) AS _current)
   INSERT INTO loan_movement (movement_date, loan_id, status
             , remaining_balance, created_by, organization_id) 
   SELECT now(), 9999999, l._current
        , calc_ending_balance(NEW.loan_id, now()::date), 1, 1
   FROM   loan l
   WHERE  l._current IS DISTINCT FROM
         (find_loan_status(NEW.loan_id, now()::date)).status;

   RETURN NULL;  -- can just be NULL for AFTER trigger
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Your `IF` expression may have been wrong in that it would not work for NULL values.

```sql
IF(_loan_movement_status != _loan_current_status) THEN
```

Only evaluates to TRUE if both values are NOT NULL and different. I rewrote with `IS DISTINCT FROM` to cover NULL values.
Also, I replaced the whole `IF` construct with a `WHERE` condition for the `INSERT` and, well, basically everything else, too.

Comment: This is really cool and deffinately not a way I thought about doing it, but unfortunately it still doesn't resolve my issue. I did try an insert on a different table and it works just fine. There's something that's tying those two together and causing something else to happen. Appreciate the help and +1 for a new approach